# mvc 5 read and display text file content

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, text-files, temporary-asp.net-files

I am trying to read a text file and display it on plage. This is what I did. But I am getting error

> The process cannot access the file
>   'D:\wwwroot\TestProject\Logs\TestLog.log' because it is being used by
>   another process.

Controller Code

```
 Array LogFileData = null;
 var logFileNameWithPath = Server.MapPath("D:\wwwroot\TestProject\Logs\TestLog.log");

 if (System.IO.File.Exists(logFileNameWithPath))
 {
    LogFileData = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(logFileNameWithPath);
 }
 ViewBag.logFileContent = LogFileData;
```

View Code

```
    @if (ViewBag.logFileContent != null) 
    {
      foreach (string dataLine in ViewBag.logFileContent) 
      {
        @dataLine
        <br /> 
     } 
   }
```

The log file is created and used by a service. My code works when I stop service. But I am not trying to write to file exclusively at the same time service is writing to it. Infact I am trying to read at a time when service is not writing to it. Any advice on how can I fix this? THanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, you need to specify the "access mode" when you try to read the file. Please take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26741191/ioexception-the-process-cannot-access-the-file-file-path-because-it-is-being). Try to open the file into a FileStream with appropriate access.

I will post some code when I can.

Comment: Thanks Henry for reply. I did knew about access mode, but did not knew how to use with File.ReadAllLines. I saw your suggested link. Also found this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12744725/how-do-i-perform-file-readalllines-on-a-file-that-is-also-open-in-excel on SO with sample code. Its working good now.