# Reading a File While Being Written to by Another Program(Windows)

Tags: c#, c++, windows

So basically, I'm trying to read a log file from a game while that game is running in order to have my program react to it in dynamic ways. I know it's *possible*, as other programs such as Notepad(++) are able to do it. However, after searching for an answer, most of what I can come up with is only Linux related.

I have no idea as to how to go about this, help in doing so with either C++ or C# would be great. Even though I would prefer native C++ over C#.

Comment: I think you need to use something like this: FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read,
System.IO.FileShare.ReadWrite). Note the FileShare mode.

Comment: As is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3560651/whats-the-least-invasive-way-to-read-a-locked-file-in-c-sharp-perhaps-in-unsaf

Comment: @alfoks After looking up the FileShare mode, that actually seems to be exactly what I need, as well as it bringing up a truckload of results for it being the resolution to my very problem; where the usual terms are so vague it's hard to find a context-specific answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The "native" winapi solution is `CreateFile`, and in particular its `dwShareMode` parameter.