# C# file is being used by another process

Tags: c#, file, io, locking

I am not sure how can I solve my problem. From time to time I get the error:
"The process cannot access the file 'xxxx' because it is being used by another proces".

Here is my method where the error happens:

```
private static void write_history(int index, int time_in_sec, int[] sent_resources)
        {
            string filepath = "Config\\xxx.txt";
            int writing_index = 0;

            if (File.Exists(filepath))
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read));
                string temp = reader.ReadToEnd();
                reader.Close();

                for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
                {
                    if (temp.IndexOf("<hst_" + i.ToString() + ">") == -1)
                    {
                        writing_index = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
            // write to the file
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filepath, true);
            writer.WriteLine("<hst_" + writing_index.ToString() + ">" + DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(time_in_sec).ToString() + "|" + sent_resources[0] + "|" + sent_resources[1] + "|" + sent_resources[2] + "|" + sent_resources[3] + "</hst_" + writing_index.ToString() + ">");
            writer.Close();
        }
```

And the error I get:

```
************** Exception Text **************
System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'Config\\xxx.txt' because it is being used by another process.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath)
```

Comment: Try putting your `StreamReader` in a `using` block

Comment: Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3560651/whats-the-least-invasive-way-to-read-a-locked-file-in-c-sharp-perhaps-in-unsaf

Comment: Are you building/re-building your project quickly? Or aborting your program regularly?

Comment: Unrelated to the question, what is the point of sleeping for 5 seconds twice? If it's an effort to make threads behave together there are better ways to waiting for threads to complete.

Comment: did you try StreamReader.Close()  - MSDN -http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.close.aspx

Comment: @Brad I agree, my guess is it was a half-ass attempt at fixing the issue at hand. OP you've got to remove those... a full 10 seconds sleeping in that method is ridiculous unless you have a *really* good reason for it to be there.

Comment: @simplecoder Uhhh... he has `reader.Close();` right there in his code.

Comment: @Doctorslo: It your function called in a multithreaded environment?

Answer (score 9):

If you have made sure that you are genuinely opening and closing the file correctly, the most likely culprit is your virus detector. Virus detectors are notorious for observing that a log file has changed, opening it up to search it for a virus, and then while it is being read by the virus checker, an attempt to write to the file fails.

If that's the case, then I would ask the vendor of your virus checker what their recommended workaround is.

Comment: Good point. OP, if you think this might be the case, it's worth it to run [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) and verify that this is the case.

Answer (score 3):

1. Use `using` around all your objects that are `IDisposable`. `using` will ALWAYS call the method `Dispose`, even if there is an exception.
2. You did close your reader, but did not close the filestream.
3. This code can be made much shorter, see my second example at the bottom of my answer.

   ```
   private static void write_history(int index, int time_in_sec, int[] sent_resources)
   {
       string filepath = "Config\\xxx.txt";
       int writing_index = 0;

       if (File.Exists(filepath))
       {
           System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
           using(FileStream stream = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)
           using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
           {
                string temp = reader.ReadToEnd();
           }

           for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
           {
               if (temp.IndexOf("<hst_" + i.ToString() + ">") == -1)
               {
                   writing_index = i;
                   break;
               }
           }
       }

       System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
       // write to the file
       using(StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filepath, true))
       { 
            writer.WriteLine("<hst_" + writing_index.ToString() + ">" + DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(time_in_sec).ToString() + "|" + sent_resources[0] + "|" + sent_resources[1] + "|" + sent_resources[2] + "|" + sent_resources[3] + "</hst_" + writing_index.ToString() + ">");
       }
   }
   ```

Shorter version:

```
    private static void write_history(int index, int time_in_sec, int[] sent_resources)
    {
        string filepath = "Config\\xxx.txt";
        int writing_index = 0;

        if (File.Exists(filepath))
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
            string temp = File.ReadAllText(filepath);

            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                if (temp.IndexOf("<hst_" + i.ToString() + ">") == -1)
                {
                    writing_index = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
        // write to the file
        File.WriteAllText(filepath, "<hst_" + writing_index.ToString() + ">" + DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(time_in_sec).ToString() + "|" + sent_resources[0] + "|" + sent_resources[1] + "|" + sent_resources[2] + "|" + sent_resources[3] + "</hst_" + writing_index.ToString() + ">");
    }
```

In case of multi threading:

```
private static readonly object _syncLock = new object();

private static void write_history(int index, int time_in_sec, int[] sent_resources)
{
   lock(_syncLock)
   {
        string filepath = "Config\\xxx.txt";
        int writing_index = 0;

        if (File.Exists(filepath))
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
            string temp = File.ReadAllText(filepath);

            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                if (temp.IndexOf("<hst_" + i.ToString() + ">") == -1)
                {
                    writing_index = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
        // write to the file
        File.WriteAllText(filepath, "<hst_" + writing_index.ToString() + ">" + DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(time_in_sec).ToString() + "|" + sent_resources[0] + "|" + sent_resources[1] + "|" + sent_resources[2] + "|" + sent_resources[3] + "</hst_" + writing_index.ToString() + ">");
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you. Your answer fits my question. I am not sure if this would work, but I'll give it a try. Also thanks for explaining using statement. (Cannot test is so fast, as I said sometimes happen and sometimes not :o)

Comment: I tested it and crash happened again :(

Comment: @DoctorSlo: Yesterday I asked: It your function called in a multithreaded environment? Can you give me that answer, please?

Comment: @DoctorSlo: In case you are using a multithreaded environment, I added another solution which is synchronized.

Comment: @Doctorslo: Another thing hit me: Do you run multiple instances of this application? If so, just at one machine or multiple machines?

Answer (score 1):

my guess is that your `FileStream`(the one you're passing into your `StreamReader` constructor) is not getting closed

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read));
```

---

Put that statement in a using statement, to make sure all your ends are tied

```
using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)))
{
    //the using statement will handle the closing for you
}
```

Comment: Though using "using" is certainly best practice here, I wonder how it can solve the problem. The OP does close the reader, and closing the reader closes the underlying stream, which in turn will dispose the stream. So given that there is no exception that prevents the code to reach the close statement (the OP doesn't mention any), how could the using statements help solving the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your method is not thread-safe. If you're accessing this method in a multi-threaded fashion, your threads could be attempting the file access at the same time. In addition to alexn's answer of properly disposing of your StreamReader, also consider using a static object outside of your method in your class and then simply locking on that before you access the file.

```
private static object lockObject = new object();

private static void write_history(int index
{
    lock(lockObject)
    {
        // Access file here
    }
}
```

Comment: Meh. I suppose this is valid, though OP didn't mention anything about multi-threading. I won't -1 but I wont +1 either.

Comment: Also I don't see anything shared among multiple threads (No need lock for files since you already get an exception if you try to oepn the same file multiple times for write)

Comment: tnw, I went with the assumption that a history writing static method could be called from multiple threads. That's why I said "If you're accessing this method in a multi-threaded fashion". That summarized my assumption and sets the context for the answer. I'm not sure I follow the point of your comment I4V. You do have to lock your access point if you want both writes to the file to succeed. I'm not saying lock the file, I'm talking about thread-locking the code. Maybe you misunderstood me?

Comment: Thanks, but this method is used only in one thread. I am sure multi threading is nt a problem.

Comment: I was having the same issue. And its working file not using this approach.
Thanks a lot.@Tombala

Answer (score 1):

Either you can use "using" or you can force the Garbage collector to release all the references.
This has resolved my issue. Review your code before applying process level or thread level changes.

example:

```
using(StreamWriter writer....)
{
  Your Code....
}
this.deleteFiles(filepath);
```

Or:

```
GC.Collect();
this.deleteFiles(filepath);
```